# Move second column in between every other row of the first first column R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is kind of the reverse of [Is there a way to move every other row in a column into a new column in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239338/is-there-a-way-to-move-every-other-row-in-a-column-into-a-new-column-in-r) but *way* above my skill level.

I have two dataframes of values from two groups I want to compare. My goal was to make a grouped histogram where there is two bars for every value. Something like this:

[image]

So I thought I would make my own frequency table and just plot the counts of every variable as a grouped barplot. I used `table()` on both matrices, merged them together, replaced `NA`'s with 0 and sorted the variable in prep for `ggplot2` with result looking a lot like this:

```
freq <- data.frame(variable = c(1:5), df1 = c(3,7,60,22097,17257), df2 = c(0,26,59,15687,12203))
freq
  variable   df1   df2
1        1     3     0
2        2     7    26
3        3    60    59
4        4 22097 15687
5        5 17257 12203
```

I have no clue how to make a plot from this. I think the dataframe that I need is this:

```
 freq
   variable   df1 source
1         1     3    df1
2         1     0    df2
3         2     7    df1
4         2    26    df2
5         3    60    df1
6         3    59    df2
7         4 22097    df1
8         4 15687    df2
9         5 17257    df1
10        5 12203    df2
```

It wouldn't take me too much time to make the real frequency dataframe by hand as there are only 27 rows, but I want to see if this is possible in R and how the advanced R people would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
freq %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = c(df1, df2), 
        names_to = "names",
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = factor(variable), y= values, fill=names))+
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly it!

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R` with `barplot`

```
barplot(`colnames<-`(t(freq[-1]), freq$variable), beside = TRUE, 
     legend.text = TRUE, col = c('red', 'blue'))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Nice base R plot! I like it.